# Passing a selected value to a new listener

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlist

since i need an action listener that has a kinda big size of code, i decided to make a new listener as a class.
My problem is that i need to pass the selected value from a scroll pane so i can take actions based on that item, it passes a null pointer since the listener is made even before i click the button that takes the action

My class is:

```
public class RecipeListener implements ActionListener{
//rest code
```

My new class constructor is:

```
public RecipeListener(ArrayList<Food> foodList, String aSelectedRecipe){
this.recipesList = foodList;
this.selectedRecipe = aSelectedRecipe;
}
```

And my implementation of listener is:

```
RecipeListener checkRecipeListener = new RecipeListener(breakfastArrayList, breakfastList.getSelectedValue());
```

press the button, having selected an item first from the list

EDIT: Here is the solution, which is passing the jlist as a parameter to the constructor and making a string inside the actionPerfomed method.
    private JList tList;

```
public RecipeListener(ArrayList<Food> foodList, JList tempList){
/*construction arguments*/
}

public actionPerfomed(ActionEvent arg0){
String selectedRecipe = (String) tList.getSelectedValue();
//rest code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your listener as following:

```
public class RecipeListener implements ActionListener{
    //rest code  
    public RecipeListener(ArrayList<Food> foodList){
        this.recipesList = foodList;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String selectedReceipe = breakfastList.getSelectedValue();
        // other processing code
    }
```

In this case value will be taken after user pressed the button.

Comment: Actually, this works, but you forgot to pass the jlist as a parameter to the constructor which means i can't use it like that since they are 2 different classes, so i can't access the jlist directly.  Anyway, your  idea worked.

Comment: @Woops Of course. You're right. I've just imagined for some reason that `RecipeListener` is an inner class. And `breakfastList` is a field in enclosing class.

Comment: Firstly i would do it  this way, but since recipeListener has to compare the names of the recipe and open the specific file, which every one is different from another, this means there is a big size of code to be written and wouldn't work having it in the same class as other gui components and some small listeners i already have.  Thanks again